# link_to omits redmine root

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, bitnami

I'm following a [Redmine Plugin tutorial](http://www.gogolek.co.uk/blog/2012/09/writing-redmine-2-x-plugins-tutorial/) and the author uses the following code in a hook, which is called from within a view, which:

```
def load_issues(count)
    (...)
    issues = Issue.find(:all, :limit => count, :order => "created_on DESC")

    issues.each do |issue|
        html = "</p> <li> 
               #{ link_to h(truncate(issue.subject, :length => 60)), :controller => 'issues', :action => 'show', :id => issue }
               </li> <p>"
    end
    return html
end
```

The returned HTML is rendered on a page. My Bitnami Redmine installation's root is `http://localhost/redmine` 
The problem is with the URL generated by `link_to`:

```
<a href="/issues/2">feature 1</a>
```

when I'm expecting something like this:

```
<a href="/redmine/issues/2">feature 1</a>
```

Other links generated by core Redmine are aware of the root and work fine, so something is missing from this implementation. I looked at some of the code in core Redmine and the `link_to` calls look just like this one though, with nothing extra added.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have exactly the same issue, this makes no sense at all. I also used the Bitnami installer, starting to wonder if it that could be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](http://www.redmine.org/issues/19024) that has now been fixed and will be in 3.0 (unfortunately no backport for 2.6).

Comment: I pulled out a lot of hairs over this one. Thanks for reporting it and getting Jean-Philippe to fix it.